# How do I switch weapons/teams without restarting the game?

Tags: openspades

Whenever I am on a computer that has the required OpenGL requirements, I will always choose to play OpenSpades instead of Ace of Spades. It's a fun game, but there's been something that I've wanted to know for a while.

How do you switch weapons or teams without restarting OpenSpades? I know the buttons are `,` and `.` in the regular Ace of Spades, but this won't work in OpenSpades.

Thanks in advance; I hope there's not something obvious that I'm missing :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You use the "L" key to Switch weapons.

Comment: Thanks Linkters ;) I found out from the buildandshoot forums also.